# What are the requirements for an outdoor zimun

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, zimun, orach-chaim

Inspired by this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/112042/33665) about an outdoor minyan, I am curious, what are the requirements for counting Jews in an outdoor zimun? Say three Jews who otherwise would qualify in a zimun ate together outside, what are the requirements for counting them? Is it similar to a Minyan with regard to having to see and hear them?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.195.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Zimmun#Obligation_of_Zimmun) article on zimmun. The important part would seem to be independent of whether you are indoors or outdoors and is:

> There is only an obligation to have a zimmun if three or more people
> eat together. The three conditions to be considered “together” is that
> those who are eating
>
> 1. eat while seated,
> 2. sit at one table, and
> 3. start or end the
>    meal together. [14] They are considered starting together if they all
>    start to eat the first kezayit of bread while the others are still
>    eating that first kezayit.[15]